# Github pages and custom tk domain

Tags: github

I'm trying to make my github page to redirect to my custom tk domain but so far nothing works

I made a CNAME file in my master branch as you can see in the link below

https://github.com/lambdaclose/lambdaclose.github.io/tree/master

And on my tk panel I added domain fowarding to my github page

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a website/application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make an A or CNAME record that points to GitHub Pages' server.
URL forwarding will not work.